# nestjs ResolveField can not return string type for handle format argument

Tags: graphql, nestjs, apollo-server, graphql-js

I am base on this demo: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/23-graphql-code-first

I want to implement the `format` argument of `creationDate` field to format date, the query is this:

```
query {
  recipes {
    id,
    title,
    ingredients,
    creationDate(format: "YYYY-MM-DD")             # <- args here
  }
}
```

And the resolver implement is:

```js
@ResolveField()
async creationDate(
    @Parent() recipe: Recipe,
    @Args('format', { nullable: true }) format?: string) {
  if(format) {
    return moment(recipe.creationDate).format(format);         // <-- error if return string
  } else {
    return recipe.creationDate;
  }
}
```

But the program throws the following error:

```json
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Recipe.creationDate.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 6,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "recipes",
        0,
        "creationDate"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "stacktrace": [
            "Error: Cannot return null for non-nullable field Recipe.creationDate.",
            "    at completeValue (/home/hungtcs/Workspaces/@temp/graphql-test/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:559:13)",
            "    at /home/hungtcs/Workspaces/@temp/graphql-test/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:469:16",
            "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)",
            "    at async Promise.all (index 3)",
            "    at async Promise.all (index 0)",
            "    at async Promise.all (index 0)"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: no/empty data? `console.log(recipe.creationDate);`